# Fastlane - Uploading to TestFlight return an error but still showing the build as available for testing

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane, fastfile

In my last two attempts to upload to TestFlight, I encountered an error from Fastlane.

```
+------+-------------------------------+-------------+
|                  fastlane summary                  |
+------+-------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                        | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | get_info_plist_value          | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform              | 0           |
| 3    | setup_circle_ci               | 0           |
| 4    | sync_code_signing             | 67          |
| 5    | build_app                     | 494         |
| 6    | dsym_zip                      | 10          |
| 7    | upload_symbols_to_crashlytics | 40          |
|    | upload_to_testflight          | 717         |
| 9    | slack                         | 0           |
+------+-------------------------------+-------------+
[09:57:06]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-    2.119.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/test_flight/client.rb:321:in     `handle_response': [!] <html> (Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse)
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 410 Gone</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 410</h2>
<p>Problem accessing     /v2/providers/118503468/apps/1372726545/platforms/ios/trains. Reason:
<pre>    Gone</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/test_flight/client.rb:31:in `get_build_trains'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/test_flight/build_trains.rb:16:in `all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/test_flight/build.rb:110:in `all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/test_flight/build.rb:121:in `all_processing_builds'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/build_watcher.rb:38:in `watching_build'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/build_watcher.rb:12:in `wait_for_build_processing_to_be_complete'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:61:in `wait_for_build_processing_to_be_complete'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:53:in `upload'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/upload_to_testflight.rb:16:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:232:in `block in execute_action'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `chdir'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `execute_action'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:154:in `method_missing'
from Fastfile:63:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:333:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:119:in `take_off'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.119.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `<main>'
```

Fastfile Code:

```
lane :beta do
    sync_code_signing(type: "appstore")
    build_app(workspace: "myapp.xcworkspace", scheme: "myapp")
    dsym_name = Time.new.strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M')
    dsym_zip(dsym_path: "./myapp.#{dsym_name}.app.dSYM.zip")
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(
    dsym_path: "./myapp.#{dsym_name}.app.dSYM.zip",
    gsp_path: "./myapp/App/AppMain/GoogleService-Info.plist")
    upload_to_testflight
    slack_success_message
end
```

I am using Fastlane 2.119.0

I'm not sure if that connected to the latest changes by Apple regarding the Two-factor authentication, as the account is already with Two-factor authentication.

After a while, I get a push notification that the build is ready for testing and I'm able to send it to Apple review. But I still have no idea why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: Same problem here, it was first encountered last Friday (2019.04.04)

Comment: There's a long thread about this issue on Fastlane's GitHub. There's a temporary branch with a fix available: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14521#issuecomment-480800319